# Is git rebase a good practice when several peoples are working on the same branch?

Tags: git

## Problematics

I have a developpement to do with a team of developpers. We decide to create a branch 'feature' from 'master' where we will commit/push your work. I do a part of the stuff we have to do and I want to test it. But meanwhile some importants hotfix have been push in master because master have some huge crash issues. I want to take advantage of the fix but I don't want to pollute the feature branch with it.

Is doing a rebase of 'feature' on the head of 'master', a good idea ? I ask this question because it end in a quite complicated state.

## History

1 -We create the branch 'feature'. Here the picture of the origin git repository with .

```
----------------[commit1]---------[dev1]
                    ^               ^
                    |               |
                 {master}       {feature}
```

2 - Then some commit have be done on master and feature, but all the developper have not pushed all theirs commits.

```
$git pull
$git branch feature

----------------[commit1]-------------------[hotfix1]
                                |              ^
                                |              |
                                |           {master}  
                                |
                                -------------[dev1]----       -------(dev2)
                                               ^                       ^
                                               |                       |
                                            {feature}    unpushed commit not yet in origin
```

3 - I decided to do a rebase and meanwhile other commit are pushed. I have resolved some conflicts

```
$git checkout feature
$git rebase master
(I resolve some conflicts)
$git commit -m "merge1"
$git rebase --continue
$git push

                                                          {feature}
                                                             |
                                                             v
                                    --------[dev1']-------[merge1]
                                    |                     /                        
----[commit1]-------------------[hotfix1]              /                           
                    |              ^                /                             
                    |              |             /                               
                    |           {master}      /                                 
                    |                      /                                   
                    -------------------[dev1]-------------     ------------[dev2]
                                         ^                                   ^ 
                                         |                                   |
                                         |                   unpushed commit not yet in origin
                                         |
                                         |
                        state of others after the rebase
```

4 - Another developper try now to push his commit dev2

```
$git fetch
(He got some conflicts)
$git commit - "merge2"
$git push



                                                                                 {feature}
                                                                                      |
                                                                                      v
                                    --------[dev1']-------[merge1]-----------------[merge2]
                                    |                     /                         /
----[commit1]-------------------[hotfix1]              /                           /
                    |              ^                /                             /
                    |              |             /                               /
                    |           {master}      /                                 /
                    |                      /                                   /
                    -------------------[dev1]-------------------------------[dev2]
                                         ^                                    ^ 
                                         |                                    |
                                         |    commit that was not pushed by another developper before the rebase
                                         |
                                         |
                        state of others after the rebase
```

Is there a better way to get the hotfix1 in the feature branch ? Because in this way it seems to just do a mess.
Knowing that I prefer to not report the hotfix1 in the branch feature, because it fix a bug in the master branch, that doesn't have any meaning in other branch (if I want to report dev1 branch into a V1 branch).

Comment: I would just cherry-pick or merge the hotfix commit.  Rebasing re-writes the commit history of all commits since the merge base of the branch.  Rebasing any shared code will cause problems like those you have described for all developers who have copies of the shared code.

Comment: But at the end I have to report the feature branch in others release branch without this hotfix. How would you do that (if I have done a cherry pick or a merge) ?

Comment: Ahh I see.  I usually do one of two things: 1) Create a local branch that contains only the hotfix commit.  Whenever I want to test, checkout `hotfix`, rebase onto `feature`, and do testing from `hotfix`.  When I need to push to origin, I checkout `feature` (which still doesn't contain `hotfix`) and push from there.  2) If `hotfix` is simple enough, I will just cherry-pick it into feature, and before I commit I will `rebase -i` to put `hotfix` at the top.  Then push all commits that come *before* `hotfix`.

Comment: Seems smart, I will try it ! But have to do the operation again, each time I have some new commits and I want to test it, isn't it ?

Comment: With #1 yes, you have to rebase every time you add new commits.  With #2, you only have to rebase before pushing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebase works by *copying* commits.  Your Git then abandons the originals in favor of the shiny new copies.

Anyone *else* who has the originals, still has the originals.  If you have them pick up your new copies, they now have both.  (And of course, whenever they have the originals, they may write their own commits that depend on those originals.)

If you and they *agree*, you can have them pick up your shiny new copies and abandon *their* originals in favor of the new ones.  (If they have their own commits that depend on the originals, they can copy those to even-newer, even-shinier commits.)  But if they *don't* agree, or are unaware of the issues entirely, they will probably get confused, *merge* their originals—with or without their own additions—with your new copies, and make a big mess and confuse everyone else too.

So the rule here is simple: rebase shared commits *if and only if* everyone agrees to this, and understands how to work their Gits.

There is an even simpler rule: *rebase only when you are the only one who has to agree with yourself.*  That is, only if your commits are "unpublished".  This rule may be too simple, in which cae you can go to the slightly more complicated version, "if and only if everyone agrees".